# difference between hide and close methods in wpf

Tags: wpf

I am currently working on wpf application. I have dialog boxes in that application. I used my custom button to close. I have two options to use in code behide event of that button.

1.

```
    private void btn_close_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

2.

```
    private void btn_close_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.hide();
    }
```

what is difference between close() and hide(). Which it better to use.

Comment: Read [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.aspx) before asking questions about methods or properties...

Answer (score 10):

[`Hide`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.hide.aspx) just hides the window, it can be shown again. Once a window is closed it is gone and will be disposed.

So only use hide if you want to reuse that instance (and don't forget about your hidden windows).

Comment: Exact. A simple search in google give you that... please 
Imran Khalil do your own search before posting questions...

Comment: @mlemay Exactly _because_ people ask these kinds of questions here and elsewhere, answers can be found quickly with a search engine.

Comment: @Feuermurmel: Well, not quite. Personally, i think most questions that can be answered by simply reading the introductory paragraph of the *official documentation* for the class/function/property in question do not need to be asked. For WPF this is often the case, given the quality of the documentation overall. Though i often just google simple questions as well and do not mind getting the answer either way.